# Returning ContentType "application/atom+xml" throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata, content-type

I am creating a mock oData feed.  The real oData feed returns `Content-Type: application/atom+xml;`.

My ASP.NET mock oData feed code looks like this.  `DoClaimsRequest()` returns JSON in string format:

```
public ContentResult Service()
{
    ContentResult result = new ContentResult();
    result.Content = DoClaimsRequest();
    result.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";
    return result;
}
```

But it generates an error with Internet Explorer "Feed format not supported", "Internet Explorer does not support this feed format."

Comment: As the error message suggests, Internet Explorer doesn’t seem to support Atom feeds. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10556973/707111.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you say that `DoClaimsRequest()` returns a json string. Just because you declare `result.ContentType="application/atom+xml"` does not mean it will be magically converted from json to atom. Have a look at the response in Fiddler...it is probably a json string. IE is told it will receive an atom response, but does not see any content that corresponds to that protocol.

Comment: Correct, and the other part of the eventual fix was to make sure DoClaimRequest() **requests** "application/atom+xml".  Remember to set content type on requests and returns.